# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called in ios swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I am working on a iOS project in swift language. It is a already written code and I am adding new features. There is a class say A: UITableViewController and has a function cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    #initialise variable
    #call a class for custom cell(say B)
    return B(#all parameters)
}

class B: UITableViewCell{
    init()
    func x(){#code}
    func y(){#code}
}
```

This is the basic code structure.

The problem I am facing is that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not working on cell click. I think the problem is with the cellForRowAtIndexPath function. I have tried adding delegate also. Basically I want that when I click a cell, It show modally present a view with navigation bar.

Hope you understood the problem. Can anybody please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function from class A. Also, is selection enabled on the tableView?  Is your class A the tableviews delegate?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath now just have a print statement.(How should I add to go to load new view)
Class A is tableviews delegate.

Comment: Still, show the code. It is one of three things - your function prototype is wrong, the delegate isn't set or selection isn't enabled on the table

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("Hello")
    }

Comment: I think the error is in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Do you see a cell in your tableView?  If so then there isn't anything wrong with cellForRowAtIndexPath. Have you checked the tableView has selection enabled in interface builder?

Comment: Also, check if UITableView Selection is set to either Single or Multiple Selection. And make sure that you set the delegate.